# Application requires log4net assembly be install in GAC first

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2015

When trying to install a VS2015 console app onto one of my servers, I get this error:

[image: This error]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/gCJHk.jpg

On another server it installs a runs just fine and the only difference I can see between the two is the the server that it does install on, has two log4net.dll in GAC. One has processor architecture of AMD64 and the other x86. And the server that the program does not install on only has the AMD64 dll. How can I install the x86 version?

I have tried regsvr32 log4net.dll command, but this give me this error:

[image: This error]
https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKHJC.jpg

Tried to drag and drop the dll to the assembly folder and says "Access Denied".

Is there a something I need to change in VS2015 before publishing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Problem solved.

First I tried the answer from Nino and gacutil.exe is not installed on that server, so I could not run that cmd.

After going through the project in Visual Studio 2015 properties/Publish settings, under Install Mode and settings, click button "Application Files..." and make sure that dll file is "included" in publishing.  The dll i needed was not included, but after including it, re-published, everything installed just fine.

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer; I had a legacy application that was having install errors for certain computers for this log4net and had no idea where to find it.  Your solution helped me get things up and running again quickly.

Answer (score 3):

you should install it into GAC using `Gacutil.exe`. Like this:

```
gacutil /i (path to dll)\log4net.dll
```

for additional documentation, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ex0ss12c(v=vs.110).aspx)

gacutil can be found here

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\xxxx\bin\NETFX yyyTools
```

where `xxx` is windows version (ie 8.1a) and `yyy` .net framework version (ie 4.6.1)

EDIT:
call gacutil.exe from Developer command prompt

```
Start -> Visual Studio 2015 Visual Studio Tools -> Developer Command Prompt for VS2015
```