# Nuget PackageReferences not copying dlls to bin directories

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2017, nuget

I'm trying to get my PCL library that uses Nuget packages to copy the dlls it requires to its output directory. For example, I use the Portable Licensing nuget, but it unfortunately does not copy its dlls to the output folder despite having tried multiple solutions/recommendations found on the web.

I've tried a few things based on this page: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/package-references-in-project-files

Manually setting IncludeAssets to all for each nuget required, locking the dependencies, using the Target build arguments found in another post, etc. Nothing seems to work.

A couple things to note:

1. I cannot set anything in terms of the nuget refrence. Pic of what my properties window looks like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/PzUhy.png
2. My project does not have a packages.json file. I created a blank project, added the nugets I needed, and copy-pasted the packages.json file from there to my main project, but it still didn't work. The blank project, when compiled, does have the dlls copied to its output directory.
3. This is a PCL project.

Can I use Nugets properly with PCL projects? Is there some setting I'm overlooking? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: PCL is obsolete, and if you switch to .NET Standard class library everything should simply work.

Comment: look at my answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837709/application-requires-log4net-assembly-be-install-in-gac-first