# Could not Load assembly file

Tags: c#, pdf, blueprism, apitron

I am trying to remove password from pdf using C# code. Initially I tried with SPIRE.pdf and then Apitron.pdf.kit dlls.

In both cases, the code was working fine in my laptop however if i try the same code using same library in my client machine, I am getting any error

> Could not load file or assembly Apitron.PDF.Kit Version=2.0.21.0
>   Culture=neural, Public Key Token=6e759db or one of its dependencies.
>   The system cannot find the file specified.

I am writing C# code in Blue Prism

Please someone advice the cause of the issue.

Comment: Is the DLL available in the output directory ? Is it working on dev machine ?  Did you check the references to see if CopyLocal is set to true on the reference ?

Comment: Take a look at my answer for this question. I think you are having similar issue. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42837709/application-requires-log4net-assembly-be-install-in-gac-first

Comment: @ManojChoudhari - Yes the dll and the supporting dll are placed in the folder and the folder is pointed in the Blue Prism code option screen. The namespace is given correctly. Its working fine in my laptop however the same code is not running in the production laptop. I checked the dll and namespace configuration and all looks fine but no clue on why its not working..

Comment: On production machine, check if dll is present and has desired version  in the required directory.  Also check if there is any third party dependency that is not available on production.